# problem with WHERE clause matching on Arabic string

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, unicode

I have a SQL Server 2005 database in which I have some tables contain Arabic text. The datatype for those fields is `NVARCHAR(n)`.

The Arabic text inside the table is appearing properly, and when selecting, they appear properly.

Th problem is that searching for Arabic text results in 0 rows.

```
select * from table_name
where name='arabic_text'
```

This retrieves no rows, where there is a name with this value.

Can you please guide me on how to write the query?

Comment: I believe you have to use `WHERE name LIKE N'[replace with arabic text]'`

Comment: @OMG Ponies Do you have to do like?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try adding N before the text e.g.

```
select * from table_name
where name=N'arabic_text'
```

Comment: The need to prefix a test comparison with "N" outside the single quotes is because of the data type (NVARCHAR), when searching by non-ASCII characters (which is why you wouldn't notice an issue searching for English text.  The N stands for "Nationalized", but means UTF (8 I assume).

Comment: there is an other problem with sqldatareader when the condtion in sql command is arabic  like this   select *from users where nam=N 'arabic text' this does not retrieve any data although there is a user name with this arabic value so what is solution

Comment: @Mohammed you're probably not going to get an answer to your .net question when its a comment inside a sql question. You're better off asking another question. Of course doing a search first is a good idea

Comment: i searched for this question on google but no answer , so i will ask another question ,thank for advice ^_^

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from table_name
where name like N'%arabic_text%'
```

will work here

Comment: i am still looking for an answer to this

Answer (score 3):

If you search for word احمد and your records have أحمد your query will return nothing even if you are using **like '%احمد%'** .
It is better to use Full-Text search.

```js
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchWord = 'احمد'

DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchString = 'FormsOf(INFLECTIONAL, "' + @SearchWord + '")' 
--SET @SearchString =  @SearchWord 

SELECT Ar.[SuraID]
      ,Ar.[VerseID]
      ,Ar.[AyahText] as Arabic
      ,En.[AyahText] as English
  FROM [QuranDb].[dbo].[ArabicQuran] Ar
  join EnglishQuran En on En.ID=Ar.ID
  where   CONTAINS(ar.AyahText, @SearchString) 
 or  CONTAINS(En.AyahText, @SearchString )
```

[Query with Full-Text (Inflectional)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017#Inflectional_Generation_Term)
[image]

Here is other example using CONTAINSTABLE [CONTAINSTABLE link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```js
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchWord = 'لا اله الا الله '

DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchString ='ISABOUT ("'+ @SearchWord+'")' 

SELECT K.RANK, Ar.AyahText,Ya.AyahText
FROM [ArabicQuran] AS Ar  
  INNER JOIN  
  CONTAINSTABLE([ArabicQuran], AyahText, @SearchString, LANGUAGE N'arabic'  ) AS K  
  ON Ar.ID = K.[KEY] 
  join EnQuranYusufAli Ya on ya.ID=Ar.ID
  order by k.RANK desc
```