# How to check duplicate record once enter a text into textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, duplicates

I've written a procedure to check duplicate record in database and return true or false but my problem is it cannot receive a nvarchar value,

```
ALTER proc  [p_Sgm_OnlineBooking_BaseInfo_CheckDuplicate]
 (
 @ParentId int,
 @Lang varchar(5),
 @TxtCheck nvarchar(MAX)
 )
 AS

BEGIN

if exists (select Value from Sgm_OnlineBooking_BaseInfo_Entries where @ParentId=ParentId and @Lang=Lang and @TxtCheck=Value
 )
select 'True'
else
select 'False'
and @TxtCheck=Value

End
```

when I execute give me wrong result :

```
exec p_Sgm_OnlineBooking_BaseInfo_CheckDuplicate 0, fa, 'استرالیا' ==> false
```

but by adding N gives me true:

```
exec p_Sgm_OnlineBooking_BaseInfo_CheckDuplicate 0, fa, N'استرالیا' ==> true
```

how to apply this N in my procedure ? i tried `N'@TxtCheck'=Value` and `'N'+@TxtCheck=Value`
but didnt work
please guide me through this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this one

declare a variable

DECLARE @pre_var int

set count result to variable

Select @pre_var = count(*)  FROM tablename WHERE conditions

now check @pre_var 
IF @pre_var = 0
BEGIN

//  insert or update or whatever

END

Comment: I tried this but my problem is the condition again. condition is the same which needs to identify the nvarchar value.

Comment: have to try like this N@TxtCheck

Comment: ref this 1 . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868188/problem-with-where-clause-matching-on-arabic-string