# how to search for Arabic charterers in recorders of DB2

Tags: vb.net

I have a table in DB2 say `premmp` wherein a column say `name` might contain Arabic characters

```
Dim s As String = "SELECT EMPNO, NAME FROM lib.PRemmp where NAME like '% " & gname.text & " %'  ORDER BY RNAME "
```

where `gname.text` is a textbox. It does not work, anyone can help me?

I write this code

```
Adapter.SelectCommand = New OdbcCommand("SELECT EMPNO, NAME FROM lib.PRemmp where NAME like ?  ", MyODBCConnection)
Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@NAME", Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = "%" & gname.Text
Adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Adapter.Fill(ds, "MyTable")
```

it solve my problem
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem with WHERE clause matching on Arabic string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868188/problem-with-where-clause-matching-on-arabic-string)

Comment: Also please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683

Comment: I have to explicitly tell DB2 that the Arabic string "at gname.text "is UNICODE.

Comment: If that was a question, then yes, you need to explicitly tell.

Comment: You should provide length for the parameter and you should not call a `select` command with `ExecuteNonQuery()` as it makes no sense.

Comment: @ZeinabHashem please post the solution that fixed your problem as an answer and edit it out of your question. This will help future visitors.